# Character Pointer and string variable

Tags: c++

I tried to use a character Pointer go throw string character (iterate) but I found i can not say the below:

```
string Name = "Hello";
char *ch = Name;
```

like the previous statements i am getting error during execution.

However when I am doing like that:

```
char *ch = "Hello";
```

the program running without throwing any exception.

Why is that?

Comment: String literals are character arrays in C++, so `char *ch = "Hello"` is valid. However, a `string` is an object, and therefore cannot be made into a character array. The `string` does have a `c_str()` function which returns the data as a character array though.

Comment: `char*` is not valid for pointing at string literals in C++11 and later, you have to use `const char*` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently encountered similar problem and the simplest answer is that `std::string` is a different type from `char*`, more precisely `std::string` is an object which contains some characters (your text) **and** few methods, which allow you to do multiple operations with your text. You can imagine creating a class Integer for storing the value, but also a method allowing you to square and cube the number which is stored in the Ingerer class. Even though they could store the same numerical value, you will not be able to compare them (unless you overload the `operator==`), as their types are different.

If you wish to use the code you provided, you need to rewrite the second line as

```
const char *ch = Name.c_str();
```

it is allowed because `std::string` contains a method `c_str()` which "casts" itself to `const char*`. If you want to learn more about strings, be sure to visit [C++ reference about strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Comment: Note that in C++ an in-memory object doesn't actually contain methods as part of its per-object RAM footprint; rather those methods are implemented as regular functions (with special syntax and access rules per the C++ spec, but that's all handled at compile time) -- methods are stored separately. What the in-memory string object might have, OTOH, is other member variables (such as e.g. a string-length integer and an allocated-buffer-size integer) in addition to the pointer-to-the-allocated-char-array, and that is what makes its in-memory layout different from a simple char-array.